# Abstract class variable vs subclass variable, which is better

Tags: java, class, variables, interface, abstract

**Background:**

```
Abstract class Animal {

  void sleep () { //implementation details.... }

  abstract void bark();
};

Class Dog extends Animal {};
Class Cat extends Animal {};

Interface House {...};
Class DogHouse implements House { ...};
Class CatHouse implements House { ...};
```

Here assume all animal have a house. Each animal will only live in its specific house. I just want to ask which places (abstract class or the subclass) is better to place this variable.

**Question:**

Which of below options is best if I want to add a DogHouse variable for Dog class?

====option 1 ====

```
public Class Dog extends Animal {
    DogHouse dogHouse = new DogHouse();
    ...
}
```

====option 2 ====

```
public Class Dog extends Animal{
    House house = new DogHouse();
    ....
}
```

====option 3 ====

```
Abstract class Animal {
    House House;

    void sleep () {... }

    abstract void bark();
}


public Class Dog extends Animal{
   Dog() {
     house = new DogHouse();
   }
}
```

Comment: That depends, if all animals have a house, and if a dog can live in a `ElephantHouse` or something simlar... Therfore, we have too little knowledge about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Julian. There is no right answer to your question; it is primarily opinion-based. As such, it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes. Here assume all animal have a house. Each animal will only live in its specific house. I just want to ask which places (abstract class or the subclass) is better to place this variable.

Comment: Please add this information to your question (edit), don't provide it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to model your situation. Here are a few suggestions:

1. If all animals are to have a house, then it makes sense to add a `House` attribute to the superclass. This ensures the attribute is available to all the subclasses, irrespective of which house it is. This applies to the model you have described.
2. If only one specific animal is to have a house,  it doesn't make sense to give all animals houses as in (1). Then you must only provide that attribute to that class for example `DogHouse` in class `Dog`.

So in conclusion, your option 3 will be better suited.